How do I create a realistic waterfall using Flip Fluids?
I'm trying to create a waterfall like this example from adobe stock. Specifically I'm struggling to get turbulent water and white water mist.
Out of the box, blender fluid simulations seem to stream together like water from a faucet. Turning on white water will make foam and spray when it collides with objects, but I can't get this kind of rough water falling.
I've tried using various shapes for the emitter, cranking up the resolution to absurd settings, using turbulence fields, even using external plug-ins like flip fluids.
Any artistic advice or direction would be appreciated.

You’re less likely to get help with an external paid add-on on this site, but even with hope that you might, you didn’t give very much info about what you were trying, or what documentation sources you were using, other than the Flip Fluids commercial. Look at the add-on documentation or a real tutorial, and try from that. Then if you’re stuck, ask for help here.

Good point. My question isn't about the plug-in specifically, and I've edited the question to reflect that. I don't have a technical question (I've worked with fluids before, read the documentation, watched the tutorials, etc.), so there's no documentation to point to. I'm just looking for advice on how to get that aesthetic.

That’s still about the addon, as you’re asking how to make it simulate fluids in a certain way. While the question is more clear than it was before, you’re far more likely to get what you need by looking up tutorials on how to make such waterfalls with the addon (or without).

I might suggest faking it with smoke to some degree, as those waterfalls almost look like vapor.

As @TheLabCat has suggested, this may look like 'a' waterfall, but for practical purposes will almost inevitably wind up being a combination of overlaid effects. So this post inadvertently conceals multiple questions, and is vulnerable to being voted 'too broad'. I really would suggest breaking it up. If you made some progress with, say, the water and its material, got stuck, and asked us for ideas about that, it would fit BSE's format a lot better... Then move on to other refinements?

You'll have a lot better luck using the particle simulator instead of a fluid solver in my opinion, since waterfall is mostly water droplets. Set the particle Physics type to fluid and crank up the particle count, lower the Interaction Radius accordingly so the fluid sticks together somewhat without blowing up.



Thank you! That's a great suggestion. I'll experiment with it.

I ended up examining the Waterfall_1a example file that comes with the flip fluid plugin and was able to get the result that I was looking for.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rVGBAyog3Uo
